# Seeking Audacious Guide

Tags: documentation, audacious

I am running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and I am desperately seeking the Manual (User Guide) to "Audacious Audio Player". Can anyone please give me a link?

Comment: Try `man audacious`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/audacious/filelist, the `audacious` package provides a `man` page that you can peruse. You should be able to find more information about the options you need from the `man` page. To view the `man` page, open the terminal and then type:

```
man audacious
```

Comment: Really? Then you might want to specify in your question what you are trying to do with the Audacious player that isn't covered in its `man` page.

Comment: The Man page didnt help any @edwinksl, I am looking for some more explained help and also some that dose`nt involve the terminal and its key use . What I need is help explained graphically. I saw that Audacious had dropped the "libaudacious - file" from v. 1.4 and if this "lib.file" is the "Help" for Audacious then this is what I am looking for.

Comment: @SpacePunk You should have specified all of these things in your question. You can't expect us to know what you have in mind if you don't write it down in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that.... I am a "clumps" when it comes to understanding this site and its behavior. Actually, I thought asking for the manual were sufficient enough.